# can't not create ckfinder servlet?

Tags: java, ckfinder3

does someone have trouble with working with ck finder 3 in java ?
I'm using IntelliJ, Java EE 8, Tool build Gradle.
I always get the problem like this, It just seem likes cannot get into the .jar lib of ckfinder:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'CKFinder': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'baseConfig'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.cksource.ckfinder.config.Config' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=baseConfig)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
        at com.cksource.ckfinder.servlet.CKFinderServlet.init(CKFinderServlet.java:180)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1441)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:1070)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:611)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:550)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:114)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:199)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.cksource.ckfinder.config.Config' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=baseConfig)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1658)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1256)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
        ... 42 more
    ]]
```

this is my file web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CKFinder</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.cksource.ckfinder.servlet.CKFinderServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>scan-path</param-name>
            <param-value>example.ckfinder</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <multipart-config>
            <location>/userfiles/*</location>
            <max-file-size>5242880</max-file-size><!--5MB-->
            <max-request-size>20971520</max-request-size><!--20MB-->
            <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>

        </multipart-config>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CKFinder</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ckfinder/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/hello.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>hello</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

and this is my custom config, I put the ckffinder.yaml in reousce folder of project.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emfIZ.png)

my build gradle setting:

```
    plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = 'https://maven.cksource.com/'
    }
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.6.2'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compileOnly('javax:javaee-api:8.0.1')
    compileOnly('javax.mvc:javax.mvc-api:1.0.0')
    compileOnly('javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:2.3.1')
    compileOnly('javax.jws:javax.jws-api:1.1')
    compile 'com.cksource:ckfinder3:3.5.1'

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: just make sure you have a bean with type com.cksource.ckfinder.config.Config or assignable from it, and you should be okay

Comment: but com.cksource.ckfinder.config.Config in jar file of dependencies

Comment: yes, register it to spring bean